# JavaCC newlines might be causing issues with parsing

Tags: java, javacc

I have a syntax that follows:

```
PARSER_BEGIN(Parser)
    package parser;
    public class Parser {}
PARSER_END(Parser)

SKIP: {
    " "
    |    "\t"
    |    "\n"
    |    "\r"
    |    "\f"
}

TOKEN : {
    <MIX: "mix">
    |    <WITH: "with">
    |    <FUNCTION: "function">
    |    <MANIFEST: "manifest">
    |    <REPEAT: "repeat">
    |    <NAT: "nat">
    |    <REAL: "real">
    |    <MAT: "mat">
    |    <FOR: "for">
    |    <INSTRUCTIONS: "instructions">
}

TOKEN : {
    <LPAREN: "(">
    |    <RPAREN: ")">
    |    <LBRACE: "{">
    |    <RBRACE: "}">
    |    <COLON: ":">
    |    <ASSIGN: "=">
}

// Include the necessary <INTEGER_LITERAL> included in most examples

TOKEN : {
    <IDENTIFIER: <LETTER> (<LETTER>|<DIGIT>)*>
    // Letter and Digit are the unicode values.
}

void Program() :
{}
{
    ( Manifest() )*
    <INSTRUCTIONS>
    Statement()
    <EOF>
}

void Manifest() :
{}
{
    <MANIFEST> (Type())? PrimaryExpression()
}

void Statement() :
{}
{
    Instruction()
    |    Function()
}

void Instruction() :
{}
{
    (TypingList())* Identifier() <ASSIGN> Expression()
}

void TypingList() :
{}
{
    Type() ( TypingRest() )*
}

void TypingRest() :
{}
{
    <COMMA> Type()
}

void Type() :
{}
{
    <MAT>
    |    <NAT>
    |    <REAL>
}

void Function() :
{}
{
    <FUNCTION> Identifier() <LPAREN> (FormalParameterList())* <RPAREN> (<COLON> TypingList())? <LBRACE>
        Statement()
    <RBRACE>
}

void FormalParemeterList() :
{}
{
    FormalParameter() (FormalParameterRest() )*
}

void FormalParameter() :
{}
{
    (TypingList())* Identifier()
}

void FormalParameterRest() :
{}
{
    <COMMA> FormalParameter()
}

void Instruction() :
{}
{
    (TypingList())* Identifier() <ASSIGN> Expression()
}

void Identifier() :
{}
{
    <IDENTIFIER>
}

void Expression() :
{}
{
    <MIX> Identifier() <WITH> Identifier() <FOR> <INTEGER_LITERAL>
}
```

This should enable me to parse a simple program, such as:

```
manifest itemOne
manifest itemTwo

instructions

function doThis(argument) : nat {
    temp = mix one with two for 3
}

two = mix item3 with item4
```

However, when JavaCC sees the `temp = mix...` statement in the function `doThis`, it states that it found an identifier, but was expecting literally anything else:
`Exception in thread "main" parser.ParseException: Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "temp "" at line x, column y.
Was expecting one of:
    "for" ...
    "}" ...`

However, as you can see, my syntax says that you can use an identifier to assign it the value of a `mix`.  But the error is saying this is invalid or incorrect.  I've tried several variants of this, but nothing is seems to work.

Comment: Does javacc show warnings? Look in the generated code if it does what you expect

Comment: What I think is happening is that the `two` or `temp` are seen as continuations of their respective subsequent lines.  This is what lead me to believe that the new lines are messing this up.

Comment: The exception is all that I really get.  It correctly identifies "temp" as an `IDENTIFIER`.  But that is about all I get.  In debug mode the transition statements only land me back at the correct conclusion: `temp` is an `identifier`.  It then sees the space (which is supposed to be skipped), puts it back, and then errors out after saying: `****** FOUND A <IDENTIFIER> MATCH (temp) ******`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is that you are telling JavaCC that there is only one `Instruction()`|`BranchStatement()|WhileStatement()|Function()`.  So once the parser visits one of those states it can no longer revisit there.

In order to fix this, put the Kleene Closure + around your `Statement()` transitions, e.g.:

```
void Statement() :
{}
{
    (
    Instruction()
    |    BranchStatement()
    |    WhileStatement()
    |    Function()
    )+
}
```

The `+` operator tells the automata that this state must be visited at least once, but can be repeated.

Comment: Since there was only one instruction in the function body, that does not explain an error reported in the function.  It would explain an error on the instruction on the last line.   I wonder if there was an error in the question.